# PHP MVC gradual transition from CodeCharge to _____?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codecharge

I'm working with a large legacy project created using CodeCharge Studio. We're looking to get away from CodeCharge, as we really don't like it (for a number of reasons).

We're not going to be able to rewrite the entire project at once, it's going to happen in increments. As a result, I need this question answered: which of the other popular frameworks is best suited to run alongside/integrated with another framework like CodeCharge as we gradually port everything over?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Zend Framework since its built and maintained by zend .  It is also built to be abstracted from an MVC Model and can work with other frameworks relativity easily